# Funções JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Foi pedido para criar um Formulário para pegar o valor de A, B e C parar as calcular equações do 2° grau e retornar o discriminante em uma tag , porém a função está retornando NaN. Código logo abaixo.

```
            <p>A: <input type = "text" id = "varA" size = "20"></p>
            <p>B: <input type = "text" id = "varB" size = "20"></p>
            <p>C: <input type = "text" id = "varC" size = "20"></p>
            <button onClick = "calcularEqua()">Calcular!!</button>

            <h1 id = "hResult">O resultado sera exibido aqui</h1>

<script>
                function calcularEqua() {
                    var inputA = document.getElementsByTagName("varA");
                    var inputB = document.getElementsByTagName("varB");
                    var inputC = document.getElementsByTagName("varC"); 

                    var a = parseInt(inputA.value);
                    var b = parseInt(inputB.value);
                    var c = parseInt(inputC.value);

                    var res = Math.pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);

                    document.getElementById('hResult').innerHTML = res;
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Substitui o getElementsByTagName por **getElementById**, pois quando você chama o getElementsByTagName você recebe uma coleção de tags.
Elements By Tag Name https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp

Element By ID:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: Tente trocar `document.getElementsByTagName` por `document.getElementsById`

Comment: Valeu @David, erro bobo, obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de utilizar o método `getElementsByTagName()` onde você buscaria os elementos pela tag, no caso `<input>`, utilize a `getElementById()`. Uma vez que esse é o argumento que você já está utilizando para a consulta ao DOM.

```js
function calcularEqua() {
  var inputA = document.getElementById("varA");
  var inputB = document.getElementById("varB");
  var inputC = document.getElementById("varC");

  var a = parseInt(inputA.value);
  var b = parseInt(inputB.value);
  var c = parseInt(inputC.value);

  var res = Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c);

  document.getElementById('hResult').innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>A: <input type="text" id="varA" size="20"></p>
<p>B: <input type="text" id="varB" size="20"></p>
<p>C: <input type="text" id="varC" size="20"></p>
<button onClick="calcularEqua()">Calcular!!</button>

<h1 id="hResult">O resultado sera exibido aqui</h1>
```